# how to downgrade Chrome on Ubuntu and disable auto-update?

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, selenium, google-chrome-devtools

I want to downgrade my chrome on Ubuntu

Because I have problems when selenium runs against Chrome 34.

I have installed chrome 33.

But then every once in a while the auto-updater update the chrome.

How can i disable the auto-upadter on Linux specifically?

Comment: These could help you : `http://askubuntu.com/questions/243394/how-to-install-specific-versions-of-google-chrome-chromium`

Answer (score 32):

I had a similar task recently. This is the script I ran to download previous Chrome version, disable auto update and check the installed version:

```sh
sudo wget http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_75.0.3770.142-1_amd64.deb && \
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_75.0.3770.142-1_amd64.deb && \
sudo apt-mark hold google-chrome-stable  && \
google-chrome-stable --version \
```

Comment: I see this installs version 75.0.3770.142.  Where can I find a list with other possible versions to downgrade to?

Comment: Thank you so much, the script has helped me. After having issues with `79+` version on some websites (e.g. YouTube, Twitter), `75` version works fine.

Comment: The exact number of google-chrome-stable to download can be found here https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/google_chrome/stable/main/base/google-chrome-stable

Comment: You can find older versions of Google Chrome here: `http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_CHROME_VERSION_amd64.deb` (replace CHROME_VERSION with the version you are looking for, e.g. 114.0.5735.198-1)

Comment: singlelinemydreamcode

Comment: Still relevant as Google Chrome 120.0.6099.216-1 seems to be broken for Intel IGP. 
Repeated errors of: ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(992)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=133
until the process exits.
119.0.6045.199-1 seems to be fine.

Comment: @Capricorn1 do you know if this is responsible for the severe echo issues in Teams PWA? Otherwise we don't have other issues with version 120.

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets I don't use Teams, so I don't have an answer for that. I couldn't get Chrome to open and render a window at all. It just printed the same error several times and exited.

Answer (score 9):

you can google to find an archive website. I have mentioned 2 of them here, though there are hundreds of them around.

0- choose the version you want to install by going to an archive website like this:
http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/pm/google-chrome-stable

1- In the Download section download the 64-Bits or 32-Bits package suitable for your OS ( or you can directly Press APT_INSTALL button)

3- Install the package using Ubuntu software center. you may need to remove the existing version first.

4- for disabling auto updates you can go to SystemSettings/ Software & Updates from Ubuntu applications Menu

Doing the same things command line:
I assume your user name is "user" you replace it with your username.

1-  Browse the website http://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php or any other archive website.

2-  Download a proper version of google-chrome ( I brought 49.0.2623.75 Linux_64)

3-  Save the downloaded file in /home/user/Downloads

4-  Open a console and execute the following commands:

```
user@host:~/workspace $ cd ~/Downloads/
user@host:~/Downloads $ 
user@host:~/Downloads $ sudo dpkg -i ./chrome64_49.0.2623.75.deb
```

of course you would replace the file name with the one you downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can search for software and updates in your dash bar
2. You can click on Softwares and updates app which is listed
3. Go to the other Software tab in the window which is opened
4. you can uncheck the http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/stable main

and then you can uninstall the new version of chrome and install the old one.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. check current version

   $ `google-chrome-stable --version`
2. find it here [google-chrome-stable for bubuntu](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/pm/google-chrome-stable), follow the link and scroll to `Changelog` section, where you can find the date when it works or just prev version
3. download it in any way. using `wget` as example (version 117.0.5938.132-1 in my case)
   $ `wget http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_117.0.5938.132-1_amd64.deb`
4. remove the old one by
   $ `sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable`
   or `apt-get purge` - to delete all the files (not recommended)
5. install downloaded package directly from file
   $ `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_117.0.5938.132-1_amd64.deb`
6. prevent update
   $ `sudo apt-mark hold google-chrome-stable`